# EF 6 auto lazy load parent navigation properties (WCF cyclic reference)

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I am trying to create a wcf service which loads data from a database through ef6 and sends the data back to the client.
Now I have a problem if I try to load dependent data from the database.

I can live with eager load so I have disabled lazy load in my context class.

```
base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Now I have a model class which references another through a navigation property.
(Here the classes)

```
public class Employee {
  public Guid EmployeeId {get;set;}

  public ICollection<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
}

public class Address {
  public Guid AdressId {get;set;}
  public Guid EmployeeId {get;set;}

  public Employee Employee {get;set;}
}
```

So as you can see Employee holds a list of addresses and one address is bound to one employee (so if I am right we have a 1:n relation)

Now as we have the model class and the datacontext I try to retrieve values from the database with this query.

```
var employee = await _context.Employees
                             .AsNoTracking()
                             .Include(x => x.Addresses)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId);
```

And here I somehow have the problem that the resulting employee class have references on itself through the inner address class. So like this

- Employee

  - Referenced Address through Address navigation property

    - Referenced Employee through Employee navigation property
    - and so on and so on

I have told ef to just include the Adress property from my Employee property. **So my question is why ef automaticaly also includes the parent Employee property in the adress property.** (I think its the behaviour of ef core with ThanInclude is there something similar in ef?)

If I am not able to stop this auto load I cant send the responding result through wcf service cause the service mention a cyclic reference.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

I had to decorate my entity classes with this.

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

and also each property with

```
[DataMember]
```

After that the serializer works as expected.